# Angular Textarea Input Problems

Tags: javascript, html, angular, textarea, angular-cli

I am new to angular and trying to learn.

I am trying to make the front-end of a basic CRUD application using the angular cli.

I have a text area called Body, the user can see his inputs before submitting the data.
The data is updated in real time .

The text-area is as follows:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="Body" class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="Enter the blog contents" name="Body"></textarea>
```

When I input text in the textarea the input is shown, but newlines just appear as spaces and the text just goes on and on in a single line without coming down to a newline.

Ex Input:

```
Hello.
I am trying.
I cannot do anything.
Please Help me.
I am a newbie.
I have to try.
Please let me.
```

Output:

```
Hello. I am trying. I cannot do anything. Please Help me. I am a newbie. I have to try. Please let me.
```

When I give HTML as input, it takes it as it is and shows all the tags changing any appearance. Eg:  is shown as  and in the inspector, it is shown as "&lt ; h1 &gt ;".

How do I fix these issues in angular cli

Comment: You can use onkeypress event on textarea and check if key pressed is enter key then append /n to Body

Comment: and how to take html input in the textarea as it takes < to be &lt; and > to be &gt;..?